# R running slower and slower on Blotter package

Tags: r

I am running some backtest using `R Blotter` package. Initially the simulation were taking just a few minutes, but with exactly the same data, they take now about an hour to run each. 
I have been creating a new `portfolio` and new account on every run (might not be the best choice) but I suspect that it is due to the the amount of `portfolio/account` that have been created.

Has anybody experienced something similar?
Is there a way to delete all the previous portfolios in the environment ?
`ls(.blotter)` shows nothing when I start the session. Not sure where is the slowness coming from. 
The Windows PC is new.

Comment: Please consider sharing code ... it might be that package, it might be unrelated, I don't know how to help without seeing what you are doing.

Comment: Hey @r2evans, Apologies but i cannot post the code as this is work related. if you are familiar with the package. Would you know how to check all the portfolio and accounts in the environment and how to delete them please/

Comment: I'm neither familiar with the package nor do I know how you are using it or the data you get from it. I understand that the code is proprietary, but I'm not going to attempt to debug your problem without seeing code, errors, or anything. Unless you are repeatedly calling `cbind` to combine new data with data from previous runs, I have no idea. (And even that idea is completely random, but a common cause of not-understood slowdowns.)